# SVG: How to reconcile text width differences between browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, typeface

I have an application that lays out multiple SVG text elements of various sizes on the screen. It's important that the text wraps consistently across browsers but I am seeing small differences between firefox and chrome.

See the following jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9eLpnjod/

We have

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     style="width:100%">
    <text id='svg_text' x="20" y="40" font-family="Verdana" font-size="35" >Example SVG text 1</text>
</svg>
```

And I simply want to get the width of the text element.

```
alert(svg_text.getBBox().width);
```

As the font family and font sizes are the same I would expect the same result. However

Chrome tells me the width is 353.46875 and FireFox tells me it is 355.45001220703125.

These are close enough but the difference is enough that it wraps differently for some cases and causes layout issues.

Is there a way to consistently measure text width in all browsers?

Thanks for any help